# undefined reference to std::experimental::net

Tags: c++, gcc, c++-ts

the code is like this

```cpp
#include <experimental/net>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

namespace net = std::experimental::net;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "networking ts stream example" << std::endl;

    net::ip::tcp::iostream s;

    s.expires_after(5s);
    s.connect("ipecho.net", "http");

    if(!s) {
        std::cout << "error: " << s.error().message() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    s << "GET /plain HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    s << "Host: ipecho.net\r\n";
    s << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    s << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    std::string header;
    while(s && std::getline(s, header) && header != "\r")
        std::cout << header << "\n";

    std::cout << s.rdbuf();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I have tried complier it by tdm-gcc 10 , fedora g++ (GCC) 11.2.1 and g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0.All of them failed,and the output are like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUtsmxu.o: in function `std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_iostream<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::basic_socket_iostream()':
a.cpp:(.text._ZNSt12experimental3net2v121basic_socket_iostreamINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEC1Ev[_ZNSt12experimental3net2v121basic_socket_iostreamINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEC1Ev]+0xd1): undefined reference to `std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_streambuf<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::~basic_socket_streambuf()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUtsmxu.o: in function `void std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_iostream<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::connect<char const (&) [10], char const (&) [5]>(char const (&) [10], char const (&) [5])':
a.cpp:(.text._ZNSt12experimental3net2v121basic_socket_iostreamINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEE7connectIJRA10_KcRA5_SC_EEEvDpOT_[_ZNSt12experimental3net2v121basic_socket_iostreamINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEE7connectIJRA10_KcRA5_SC_EEEvDpOT_]+0x4f): undefined reference to `std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_streambuf<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >* std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_streambuf<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::connect<char const (&) [10], char const (&) [5]>(char const (&) [10], char const (&) [5])'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUtsmxu.o: in function `std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_iostream<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::~basic_socket_iostream()':
a.cpp:(.text._ZNSt12experimental3net2v121basic_socket_iostreamINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEED1Ev[_ZNSt12experimental3net2v121basic_socket_iostreamINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEED1Ev]+0x4d): undefined reference to `std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_streambuf<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::~basic_socket_streambuf()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUtsmxu.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE[_ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_streambuf<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::~basic_socket_streambuf()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUtsmxu.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE[_ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE]+0x18): undefined reference to `std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_streambuf<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::~basic_socket_streambuf()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUtsmxu.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE[_ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_streambuf<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::setbuf(char*, long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUtsmxu.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE[_ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE]+0x40): undefined reference to `std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_streambuf<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::sync()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUtsmxu.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE[_ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE]+0x58): undefined reference to `std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_streambuf<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::underflow()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUtsmxu.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE[_ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE]+0x68): undefined reference to `std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_streambuf<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::pbackfail(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUtsmxu.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE[_ZTVNSt12experimental3net2v122basic_socket_streambufINS1_2ip3tcpENSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockENS1_11wait_traitsIS7_EEEE]+0x78): undefined reference to `std::experimental::net::v1::basic_socket_streambuf<std::experimental::net::v1::ip::tcp, std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::experimental::net::v1::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::overflow(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what's wrong with them? My complier option is '-std=gnu++2a' or '-std=c++2a',both do not work.

Comment: Aside from compiling with `-std=gnu++2a` or `-std=c++2a`, exactly how are you building your program?

Comment: What is the most minimal possible program you can write that generates a linking error with `std::experiment::net`?

Comment: actually it was this line, net::ip::tcp::iostream s; and also is the tcp::socket class, I compiler it with g++ main.cc -std=gnu++2a.

Comment: I am by no means an expert with these experimental features, but given that you're running into linker errors, it looks like your compilation isn't the issue, but rather linking to the necessary libraries.

Comment: That is really strange. I can confirm it fails with all known compilers and there seems to be no documentation. Even on trunk it fails...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For GCC 13 it seems you have to link with flag `-lstdc++exp`

From GCC docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.experimental

> GCC 13 includes an implementation of the C++ Contracts library defined
> by P1429R3. Because this is an experimental extension, not part of the
> C++ standard, it is implemented in a separate library, libstdc++exp.a,
> and there is no shared library for it. To use the library you should
> include <experimental/contract> and link with -lstdc++exp.